# Stateful Classes Flutter project

Tags: flutter, react-native, null-safety

I'm trying to generate a Flutter app, to create a stateful text field that I can call from other class (passing a name of the field and a limit for the field)., but I don't know how to do that,

Basically, I'm trying to be concise and reduce the amount of code for (variables)consecutive text fields.

**Could someone help me?**

Comment: Could you maybe add an example of what you’ve tried? It makes it easier to answer the question.

Comment: fine @Buzzyy , I will do it now . thank you for advice

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter, you don't usually work like that.

Instead, use [state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) classes to store any manage state information, and provide a Stream instance that is then used to update your widgets (TextField) when state changes.

Comment: thank you Ber, I will review documentation then try it.